# Spring Cloud Gateway Webflux Okta

Tags: reactjs, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

All Okta request is block by server due to cors.My Code is as below. Please help me.Below code is not working

@Bean
fun securityWebFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
return http
.httpBasic().disable()
.formLogin().disable()
.oauth2Login().and()
.csrf{it.csrfTokenRepository(CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository())}
.authorizeExchange()
.pathMatchers("/actuator/health").permitAll()
.pathMatchers("/**").authenticated()
.and().build()
}

```
@Bean
fun corsConfigurationSource() : CorsConfigurationSource {
    val corsConfig = CorsConfiguration()
    corsConfig.apply {
        allowedOrigins = mutableListOf("*")
        maxAge = 3600L
        addAllowedMethod("*")
        addAllowedHeader("*")
    }
    val source = UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource()
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfig)

    return source
}
```